# React Apollo Client How to unsubscribe from a Subscription Server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am using useSubscribe hook to connect to the backend, and all of the examples about unsubscribing from the that I saw is written in class components and they were using the old versions of Apollo. I just couldn't figure out that how to unSubscribe from an Apollo GraphQL Subscriptions Server. My code to subscribe:

```
  const { data, loading } = useSubscription(COMMENTS_SUBSCRIPTION, {
    variables: { uuid },
  });
```

Comment: Unmount the component.

Comment: I tried but the connection is still alive. Can I unmount a component manually?

Comment: Setup a toglle button to hide and seek that component:
`{display && <SubscribedComponent />}`

Comment: unsubscribe will be called automatically when the component unmounts.